# Configuring Gunicorn: No application module specified

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy a django project with NGINX and gunicorn. I keep getting 502 Bad Gateway. I've been working nonstop on this for the past few days and I can't seem to get this deployed. I've gone through 3 tutorials on Digital Ocean, but they aren't correct, obviously.

I keep getting 502 bad gateway, or if I try to use manage.py runserver, I get 400 bad request.

I think my problem is with gunicorn. When I enter gunicorn -config, it says

```
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE] gunicorn: error: No application module specified.
```

Every bit of documentation I can find says to simply type gunicorn wsgi:application, but when I do, it says "workers failed to boot." How do I set an application module?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you have nginx proxying to port 8001, you want to do this:

gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8001 your_project_name.wsgi:application

You need to run that from your project folder (where the manage.py file is)

Comment: When I do that, now I get Server Error (500)

Comment: That means theres a bug in your code. Check your logs.

Comment: Following this DigitalOcean tutorial (https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-deploy-flask-app/), I needed to change the deploy command to `gunicorn --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm app:app`, as the default command did not work.