# Problem in running (flask+) gunicorn using supervisor: no application module specified

Tags: flask, gunicorn, supervisord

all. Got a weird problem in running gunicorn with supervisor to serve a flask application. Before I start stating my problem, just want to say that I'm aware of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748015/configuring-gunicorn-no-application-module-specified). Nevertheless, my problem was that I could run gunicorn directly in the foreground to server the app. The problem only occurred when I used supervisor.

Here's the structure of my flask application:

```
myproject/
|---webapp/
|   |---__init__.py    # create_app function is here
|   |--- ...           # other files in webapp
|---wsgi.py
|---manage.py          
|---venv               # gunicorn is in venv/bin
```

The `wsgi.py` file looks like the following

```py
from webapp import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Sitting in `myproject` directory, I can launch the app by running

```sh
$ venv/bin/gunicorn -w 4 wsgi:app
```

Then I created a `webapp.conf` in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/` directory, as follows.

```
[program:webapp]
directory=/home/<my username>/projects/myproject
command=/home/<my username>/projects/myproject/venv/bin/gunicorn -w 4 wsgi:app
user=<my username>
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=<some path>
stderr_logfile=<some path>
```

When I reloaded my `supervisor`, the stdout log file said

```
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE] gunicorn: error: No application module specified.
```

My question is, why do I get an error here if I don't get an error when running gunicorn directly? What's the difference?

By the way, I then tried to use `systemd` to run the gunicorn following [this post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04), and `systemd` can launch the gunicorn service normally.

Any idea what I did wrong with `supervisor`? Thanks very much.